# Set width for ComboBox

Tags: office-ui-fabric

I have a ComboBox as follows:

[image]

How can I set the width of both 1 and 2 the same?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ComboBox](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric#/components/ComboBox#Implementation) has a property called `useComboBoxAsMenuWidth` when you set it will make sure it matches the menu width.

Here is a codepen https://codepen.io/mohamedhmansour/pen/ZqdEMY

Answer (score 0):

Using `useComboBoxAsMenuWidth` works but if there are wide menu items they are truncated.

Here is how to ensure minimum width the same as ComboBox, but allow the menu to grow wider if needed:

```
<div style={{ width: "12rem" }}>
  <ComboBox styles={{ callout: { minWidth: "12rem" } }} />
</div>
```